What does that 55% mean in the final message from rsync?
I was wondering how to read the final message after rsync finished a task:
user@host:/mnt> rsync -arH --no-i-r --info=progress2 temp/ /mnt/dir1/
1,506,924,402,411  55%   68.74MB/s    5:48:27 (xfr#1180, to-chk=0/2530)

I'm curios about that 55%: shouldn't be 100% since the transfer completed (I think successfully...)?

Did you perform a checksum of the file?

I'm not sure, what do you mean? I posted the command I used for the rsync operation.

You need to verify the checksum of the file to confirm it copied correctly. sha1sum -c filename. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61826/how-do-i-check-the-sha1-hash-of-a-file

The reason why rsync shows 55% instead of 100% it's because of hards links and their preservation via the -H flag.
I made a small test to explain the result.
user@host:~> ll old_disk/*
-rw-r--r--. 2 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 old_disk/logs_hardlinks.txt

old_disk/dir1:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 2 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 logs.txt

Running rsync:
user@host:~> rsync -arH --no-i-r --info=progress2 old_disk/ new_disk/
             15  50%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/4)

As it's shown, only 50% of the source was transferred since I passed the -H flag. Hard link were preserved in the destination as expected:
user@host:~> ll new_disk/*
-rw-r--r--. 2 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 new_disk/logs_hardlinks.txt

new_disk/dir1:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 2 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 logs.txt

If we drop the -H flag, the transfer will be 100% and no hard links will be preserved:
user@host:~> rsync -ar --no-i-r --info=progress2 old_disk/ new_disk/
             30 100%   14.65kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=0/4)
podman@host:~> ll new_disk/*
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 new_disk/logs_hardlinks.txt

new_disk/dir1:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 15 Aug 12 22:10 logs.txt


rsync uses a delta-transfer mechanism so it does not necessarily transfer an entire file, only the changes/differences. This can be changed with options such as:
--whole-file, -W         copy files whole (w/o delta-xfer algorithm)
The percentage shows that the transfer only sent 55% of the source file total because that's all that was required. See here and here for some more info.

That's what I understood as well. However, I used rsync to move files/dirs from one disk to another and the target destination was completely empty when I started the transfer.

Is it perhaps because I passed the -H flag to preserve hard links and so not really "all" files were needed?
